# How can I get value based on name with multiple ng-model with unique name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I get value based on name? ng-model is the same but name is unique.

```
<input type="text" name="name1" ng-model="field.value">
<input type="text" name="name2" ng-model="field.value">
```

I tried with following code, but no luck! I wanto to show `'some value'` only in the name contains name1.

```
if(document.getElementsByName('name1')){
  $scope.field.value = 'some value';
}
```

Comment: i can't figure out what you want to do , could you explain your problem more ?

Comment: What does *" show Show Value"* mean? Not clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Approach is definitely wrong, you shouldn't be querying the dom and should be storing state in controller model

Comment: The `ng-model` directive creates a two-way binding between an input and a scope variable. If the scope variable is the same, any changes to the scope variable will update both inputs. Any changes to either input will update the model and automatically update the other input. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi just a suggestion please be more descriptive while asking question. It might help other to understand the question.

**Problem:** 
As far as I know you want to show changed value in input text field having name **"name1"**. But int your case a common variable (***field.value***) is associated with both the input text field, so any change in field.value will affect both.

**Solution:**
**There are two cases:**
 1. You even don't want to show the input text field.
 2. You don't want to change the value of input text field.

**Solution For Case-1**
You can you take one boolean variable and use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive with that.

```html
<input type="text" name="name1" ng-model="field.value">
<input type="text" ng-if="showfFlag" name="name1" ng-model="field.value">
```

**Solution For Case-2**
You can take one boolean variable and use that to change the modal value for your input text.

```html
<input type="text" name="name1" ng-model="field.value">
   <!-- showFlag === true? field.value: " "" 
   If flag is true then show value else return 
   old value of empty string depends on you requirement. 
   You can change that function in your controller.
   -->
<input type="text" name="name2" ng-model="showFlag === true? field.value: " "">
```